# can a task have two outgoing sequence flow and message flow out of it?

Tags: bpmn

BPMN example. Visio is not accepting this, but I have seen it online in many examples

[image]

Issues

1. Can the task have the outgoing sequence and the message sequence outgoing as shown?
2. Couldn't the intermediate event receive a direct message sequence as shown there?

[image]